# What is the meaning of: New Horizons' communication rate at 1kbit/s between the probe and Earth?

Tags: communication, new-horizons, pluto

Is it a real-time communication rate measure? As in it would take one second to receive 1 kbit from Pluto?

Comment: Effectively, yes.

Comment: ? I recall 2 estimates. Earth is 8 light minutes from the sun, and Pluto is 30AU minimum from sun. 240 minutes for data to reach us from Pluto. Give or take. Once it starts flowing you get 1kb/sec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rate is the maximum data rate from New Horizons to Earth, assuming the 70m dish is being used, and there isn't significant data loss. See [this article from the Planetary Society](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2015/01300800-talking-to-pluto-is-hard.html).

Comment: Thank you @PearsonArtPhoto. So 1kbit/s is the rate of communication after the 1st bit got received, i.e. after the 4,5 hours that the signal takes from Pluto to Earth. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.